# Preselect an item in a dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to populate a list of userIds in a select menu. That's working great. On the second step, I want to pre-select a specific user. I found out when I initialise the variable selectUsers with `selectUsers : string = "16"` (16 is a existing userId) then it works. But actually, in the reality I have not yet the userId which should be selected. I want to assign it in the `ngOnInit()` method. I tried  `this.selectUsers = "17"`, but it seems to be ignored. Only the initialise value seems to count.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectUsers" name="users" required>
     <ion-option *ngFor="let userId of userIds" [selected]="(userId == selectUsers) ? 'true' : 'false'">{{userId}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `true` and `false` with single quotes which is taken as a string literal and will always be truthy. So `[selected]` is always true irrespective of the condition.

Try:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectUsers" name="users" required>
     <ion-option *ngFor="let userId of userIds" [value]="userId" [selected]="(userId == selectUsers) ? true : false">{{userId}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Or:

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectUsers" name="users" required>
         <ion-option *ngFor="let userId of userIds" [value]="userId" [selected]="(userId == selectUsers)">{{userId}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed this. Maybe this was a 2nd bug in my code. But I still have the problem, that i cant assign for example: `this.selectUsers = "17"`

Comment: you could do `this.selectUsers=this.userIds[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

To pre-select an option, assign the selected value to the property `ngModel` is bound to:

```
[(ngModel)]="userId" (ngModelChange)="selectUsers = $event"
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you be more specific.. which variable I have to assign in the *.ts with the userId which I want to select.

Comment: One of the items from the array you use to create `<ion-option>` elements ( `of userIds`)